# Stack Exchange creator's (official?) take on pastebin, fiddles, images, et cetera

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle

What is the "official" take on sharing code/images/etc on SE sites?

By "official" I mean I'm looking for any thoughts on this by the creators of the SE engine/software. Note that I appreciate the great answers that have been given by mods and community members to the more specific questions (often about a specific service).

I'm happy to accept the answer "there isn't any" if that's the case. It's just curiousity I'm trying to satisfy.

PS. Here's some linked questions that are related yet don't answer my question:

- [When jsFiddle and other related sites are gone, so is the information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114942/when-jsfiddle-and-other-related-sites-are-gone-so-is-the-information)
- [Custom jsFiddle for StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49728/custom-jsfiddle-for-stackoverflow)
- [Link or copy paste code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20692/link-or-copy-paste-code)
- [A stack exchange brand “pastebin”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70043/a-stack-exchange-brand-pastebin)

Related blog posts:

- [New Image Upload Support](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/)

(If any other linked questions or related posts show up in comments I'll try to add them to the list.)

Comment: Images: [New Image Upload Support](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) on the blog. Use that please, to secure images.

Comment: Link-only answers (and Q's indecipherable without an external link) must die! Die! DIE!

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114942/when-jsfiddle-and-other-related-sites-are-gone-so-is-the-information

Comment: Don't forget that this is largely a community-policed site; the creators implement features and occasionally, ahem, [strongly advocate certain policies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97290/159251), but generally speaking, the mores are decided by the users. Their answers are just as valuable, if not more so, than Jeff's or any other team member's on matters of social conduct on SE.

Comment: Here's one of my auto-comments, which gives you an idea on the preferred stance: "Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference."

Comment: Thx for all the comments. I've added related SO Meta questions to my original question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The de facto answer seem(s/ed) to be that "there is no official stance". The closest thing though is a [new initiative by Stack Exchange to create its own fiddling-feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/419956). Some relevant excerpts from that post:

> **What do Stack Snippets do?**
>
> Stack Snippets make code blocks runnable.

And a little later on (some of the emphasis mine):

> **Why?**
>
> Every question is better for having minimal, reproducible code. **Right now the best way to tell people to do that is to point them to jsFiddle, which is off-site. Using this feature, we plan to push new posters to embed runnable code that reproduces their problem.**
>
> Similarly, answers that include runnable code are easier to use and understand, because you can try them out. Obviously jsFiddle is hugely popular in answers already, so we just wanted to make it even easier to use.
>
> Obviously the same rules apply: code-only questions or answers will still be blocked (and, in fact, because of how it's implemented all the existing checks will just work out of the box).